# How to approach a Poisson's Equation of a square domain

Tags: poissons-equation

As someone with severe Asperger's I can't understand programming and after 100s of hours trying to learn it just doesn't click.

I am looking for any suggestions on material to learn to solve an equation such as

Poisson equation on a square domain of 51 by 51

$$U_(xx_) + U_(yy_) = xy $$

$$(0,y)=0;    (x, 0)=0;    _(51,y)=;    u_n(x, 51)=y$$

Comment: Hey! Do you want to employ Finite Elements? This is a self-contained reference with some hints on programming: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-49316-9

Comment: I hate programming, and would prefer to learn how to do the concepts by hand. That's where the fun is.

Comment: It depends on the points of view, but I understand yours. In any case, I still would suggest Quarteroni's textbook for theory on Finite Elements